# How to change the icon which used as a nav link?

Tags: jquery, css

I used icon as a nav link.Icon must be changed to another icon while it is active.then again it must be converted into first icon while moved into another link with help of jQuery and css image sprites.

```js
$("div").click(function() {
  $(".login-normal").toggleClass("login-sel");
});
```

```css
.login-normal,
.login-sel {
  display: inline-block;
  background: url('log12.png') no-repeat;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  text-align: left;
}

.login-normal {
  background-position: -0px -0px;
  width: 47px;
  height: 60px;
}

.login-sel {
  background-position: -0px -60px;
  width: 47px;
  height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="login-normal"></div>
```

Comment: show your effort, where is your code?

Comment: definitely I will show my code.I am going to show it in editing section of question within 5 mins. Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made an example with a random sprite since yours is not available here. Changes are documented in the CSS code.

You will need to change the width, height and sprite coordinates according to your own sprite dimensions.

```js
$("div").click(function() {
  $(".login-normal").toggleClass("login-sel");
});
```

```css
.login-normal,
.login-sel {
  display: inline-block;
  background: url('https://coderwall-assets-0.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/picture/file/642/humans.jpeg') no-repeat;
  /* overflow: hidden; Not necessary */
  /* text-indent: -9999px; Not necessary */
  /* text-align: left; Not necessary */
}

.login-normal {
  background-position: -0px -0px;
  /* width: 47px;
  height: 60px; */
  width: 180px; /* Added for these sprite dimensions */
  height: 150px; /* Added for these sprite dimensions */
}

.login-sel {
  /* The other image is located 150 pixels lower. X-axis does not change */
  background-position: -0px -150px;
  /* width: 47px; Not necessary */
  /* height: 60px; Not necessary */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="login-normal"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery you could try something like this.

```
.active{background: url('images/active.png');}

$('#nav').live('click',function () {
   $('.active').removeClass('active');
   $(this).addClass('active');
});​
```

There is also a CSS active selector

```
a:active { 
    // your style here
}
```